# Question about installing Ubuntu on a UEFI system?

Tags: uefi, live-usb, lenovo, windows-10, bios

I am going to be installing Ubuntu on a UEFI system for the first time, however I a bit hesitant. 
I will be replacing Windows 10 (upgraded from 8) with Ubuntu

I am going to disable secure boot as I am getting the message from within Ubuntu that it must be to be installed.

However my concern is that to access UEFI, I must access it from within Windows by holding shift during reboot. There is no keyboard shortcut on this Lenovo laptop being displayed during a boot.
So I wonder once I have installed Ubuntu, how will I get back into UEFI? Say if I had to boot from a USB drive in the future?

Comment: The reason that you're not able to get into UEFI other than from Windows is probably because you have Fast Startup on - try turning that off and see where that gets you

Comment: Directions for disabling it: https://askubuntu.com/a/843161/518562

Comment: Besides Windows fast start up, is the UEFI fast boot. That assumes system has not changed to the UEFI/BIOS scan of system is still valid and it immediately starts/jumps to booting system. Best to have that off, especially when reconfiguring system. Also "cold" boot usually forces UEFI to scan system, but with laptop you may have to remove battery &  hold power switch for 10 sec or so to drain all power. Otherwise it just does warm reboot. Some models of Lenovo need UEFI updates to work with Ubuntu.Lenovo boot screen can be accessed by Fn + F2 keys, boot device selection by Fn + F12.

Comment: @AndroidDev I have Fast Boot disabled. :)